# Linux: how to rename cdrom drives

Tags: debian, data-cd

I'm running Debian. I've changed computer, migrating the root partition, a few times. My cdrom drive is listed as /dev/cdrom3. This does sometimes cause some problems. I'd like to rename it to /dev/cdrom0. I was able to rename my ethernet card to eth0, but cannot find instructions on how to do this. Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules`
Simply look for the line that contains the entry `SYMLINK+="cdrom3"` and rename it to your liking.

To make the changes take effect, I think a simple restart of `udev` would work (`service udev restart`) although you might need a reboot.

Comment: @stefa.rossi Out of curiosity, did you have to reboot?

Comment: FYI: I had the same problem and I had to reboot. Anyway, thanks for the info.